# Как запустить sshd в rescue?

Tags: ssh, linux

Есть ли возможность, например, в rescue centos запустить sshd ?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно.. поднимите сеть (service network start) и затем service sshd start

Comment: А по делу можете что то сказать? Неужели Вы думаете, что Я не знаю как поднять сеть и запустить демон? Ну К.О.В стандартном rescue нет sshd

Comment: Что вы понимаете под rescue? образ или runlevel?

Comment: rescue - это linux rescue  при загрузке с DVD ? Я почему то подумал про single mode..

Comment: Я вот тоже подумал что ТСу надо бы пояснить.

Comment: >rescue - это linux rescue при загрузке с DVDименнона любом сетапном диске с centos есть, образ запускается коммандойlinux rescueвопрос тот же, как запустить на нем sshd ?

Comment: Тогда никак!

Comment: нашел образ с sshd и еще кучей фич http://www.sysresccd.org